# How do I inject a custom Executor into a play application?

Tags: java, akka, playframework-2.4, playframework-2.5

I have assigned a dedicated thread pool for database operations via play-akka configuration file. For now I am injecting the services that require this thread pool with the actor system and accessing the execution context.

```
 public class ServiceA{

     final Executor executionContext;

     @Inject
     public ServiceA(ActorSystem system) {
        this.executionContext = system.dispatchers().lookup("akka.actor.db-context");
 }
```

But this makes it hard to test ServiceA. What I would like to do instead is just inject the Executor directly like this:

```
 public class ServiceA{

     final Executor executionContext;

     @Inject
     public ServiceA(Executor dbExecutionCtx) {
        this.executionContext = dbExecutionCtx;
 }
```

How do I achieve this? I have tried creating a guice module to inject the Executor but it errors out complaining that there is no started application and doesn't have access to ActorSystem when its doing it's binding the classes.

Answer (score 1):

I use a pattern where I can get EC anywhere I want. I create an `ActorSystem` in a Singleton and get it injected into my services.

I have a design with ActorSystems, Dispatchers and a lot more for monitoring. Have a look at this and see if you can integrate it.

So if MyActorSystem is injected to your class you can access the EC from it. Have a look at `MyDispatcher` and the use of EC:

```
@Singleton
public class MyActorSystem implements IMyActorSystem{

    ActorSystem system;
    public MyActorSystem() {
        system = ActorSystem.create();

    }

    public ActorRef create() {
        final ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(
                Props.create(MyWorker.class).withDispatcher("my-disp")
        );
        return actor;
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        system.shutdown();
    }

    public ExecutionContextExecutor getDispatcher(){
        return system.dispatcher();
    }
    }

    public class MyDispatcher implements IMyDispatcher {

    MyActorSystem system;

    @Inject public MyDispatcher(MyActorSystem system) {
        this.system = system;
    }


    public CompletableFuture<Object> dispatch(final Object story) {
        List<CompletableFuture<Object>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
        final ActorRef actor = system.create();
        final CompletableFuture<Object> completed = FutureConverter
                .fromScalaFuture(Patterns.ask(actor, story, 50000)).executeOn(system.getDispatcher())
                .thenApply(i -> (Object) i);
        return completed;
    }

    public ExecutionContextExecutor getDispatcher(){
        return system.getDispatcher();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's kind of what i ended up doing too. Now you have to call methods like getDispatcher(),but its an improved solution. I was trying to explore if there were other ways to just inject the executor directly without any additional method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Play as of 2.6 exposes DI bindings for its default dispatcher like this:

```
bind[ExecutionContextExecutor].toProvider[ExecutionContextProvider],
bind[ExecutionContext].to[ExecutionContextExecutor],
bind[Executor].to[ExecutionContextExecutor],
```

where `ExecutionContextProvider` is

```
@Singleton
class ExecutionContextProvider @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem) extends Provider[ExecutionContextExecutor] {
  def get = actorSystem.dispatcher
}
```

It looks like Play does not expose other named dispatchers in DI bindings, so you can do it yourself the same way but using `@Named` bindings. It is also possible to write a Play DI module which would dynamically expose all named akka dispatchers as corresponding named bindings.